# How to refactor client js in apostrophecms

Tags: javascript, refactoring, apostrophe-cms

I am having one large `.js` file in `module -> public -> js -> always.js`. I want to divide this file into 2 to 3 files as it's having thousands of line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the script into as many other files as you want. For example, if you divided it into 3 scripts (e.g. always.js, utilities.js, somethingelse.js), you can push them to the browser by using the pushAsset method inside of your module. So, you'd add this to the construct method of your module's index.js:

```
///lib/modules/my-module/index.js
construct: function(self, options) {
  self.pushAsset('script', 'always', {when: 'always'});
  self.pushAsset('script', 'utilities', {when: 'always'});
  self.pushAsset('script', 'somethingelse', {when: 'always'});
}
```

The scripts you add via pushAsset will be available on the browser when you visit any page on your Apostrophe site. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Joseph! And in new file i.e. `utilities` we have to write like `/* global apos */
apos.on('enhance', function () { console.log('ds') })` to see the file working.

Comment: Yep, good idea - that's a good way to test that the script is actually being included and used. Glad it's working!

Comment: Yes Joseph it's working now but my next problem is with `self` object which I can't get in new files as I can't write constructor there in newly created files which is present in `module -> public -> js -> utilities.js` for example. i am calling `self.getData()` in `always.js` and I want it to be defined in `utilities.js` or in vice-versa files. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: You can actually use constructors in those files as well! Instead of using extend, however, you should use upgrade. This will add to the module, instead of replacing it. So, you would leave your original always.js file the same, but instead of doing this in the new file:
"apos.define('my-widget', {extend: 'apostrophe-widgets', construct: function (self, options) {...." you would do this: "apos.define('my-widget', {upgrade: 'my-widget', construct: function (self, options) {....". Then you'll have access to self, and as long as you don't re-use function names, nothing will get overwritten.

Comment: Actually, there is no special upgrade option, but the default behavior you are getting there is what you want: it extends the class while keeping the same name.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I've been using upgrade in this way a few times up to now, so it's good to know it's actually defaulting to extend the class.

Comment: Joseph, Upgrade is not working at my end and unable to use `self` in another file by extending the class too.